# Converting Byte[] to a Int8

Tags: c#

Is there any way to convert a Byte[] into a int8?  I have been given a binary file that contains a list of input parameters for a test.  The parameters vary in size from uint32 down to uint8.  I am having no problem reading in the file, what is tricky is getting the values to display in the GUI.

Here's is the basis of what I'm doing:

```
private Byte[] blockSize;
private Byte[] binSize;

FileStream filen = File.OpenRead(file);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(filen);

blockSize = br.ReadBytes(4);
binSize = br.ReadBytes(1);
```

No problems with that considering that the first 32 bits (4 bytes) of the parameter file are the blockSize and the next 8 bits (1 byte) are the value for my binSize variable.  Where the problem comes is in displaying it.

```
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToInt32(blockSize, 0).ToString();
textBox2.Text = BitConverter.ToString(binSize, 0).ToString();
```

Lets say that my binary input file contains the following 5 bytes of data "0A 00 00 00 0A".  My first textbox displays '10', my second textbox displays '0A'.  I want the hex value converted into the more human understandable decimal value.  It seems to work fine as long as the parameter in the input file is greater than 1 byte so I can easily convert it using ToInt16 or ToInt32, but I have nothing for the 8bit variety.

Comment: how is this possible at all ?  Byte[] into a int8?

Comment: What do you mean int8? No such thing.

Comment: int8=Byte. Byte[] into Byte? Omg.

Comment: @viveknuna, it is possible if byte array have only one element :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem that `r.ReadBytes(1);` return `byte[]` then your call `BitConverter.ToString(bytearray)` with byte array as parameter which do the next:

> Converts the numeric value of each element of a specified array of
>   bytes to its equivalent hexadecimal string representation

`BinaryReader` has methods

```
int ReadInt32()
byte ReadByte()
```

Change types of `blockSize` to `int` and `binSize` to `byte` and use those methods

```
int blockSize = br.ReadInt32();
byte binSize = br.ReadByte();

textBox1.Text = blockSize.ToString();
textBox2.Text = binSize.ToString();
```

From MSDN:
`ReadInt32()`

> Reads a 4-byte signed integer from the current stream and advances the
>   current position of the stream by four bytes.

`ReadByte()`

> Reads the next byte from the current stream and advances the current
>   position of the stream by one byte.

Comment: Ok, my problem was that I was using ReadBytes(1) rather than ReadByte().   When I tried to store ReadBytes(1) as a byte I got an error, but when using ReadByte it works.  Thanks for the help.